# In Angular Material, how to md-sidenav always open

Tags: angular-material

visible toggle button and close it whenever I want?

I've done several attempts and failed.

I uploaded the picture as it is today, but it does not toggle, only at lower resolutions.

Any idea how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 26):

I had a lot of trouble finding a way to do this in material2.
Finally, I found this way reading the source code:

```html
<md-sidenav opened="true" disableClose="true">
```

Answer (score 5):

For newer versions, add `[opened]="true"` to your `<md-sidenav>` element

```
<md-sidenav [opened]="true">

</md-sidenav>
```

Answer (score 4):

my side-nave closed when I press Esc button. Then I added

> `<mat-sidenav mode="side" opened [disableClose]="true">`

which solved my problem.

1. toggle sidenav with a checkbox: https://stackblitz.com/angular/ldeyaoygrmn?file=app%2Fsidenav-open-close-example.html
2. toggle sidenav with a Button click: https://stackblitz.com/angular/pdxjaplpmav?file=app%2Fsidenav-disable-close-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the Navbar open for any view you wish by adding the below attributes to it:

```
md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')"
```

Check [Angular Docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSidenav) to refer.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code snippet. Basically you can use `$mdSidenav("sidenavId").toggle()` to toggle the sidenav.

```js
angular.module('materialApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate'])

.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', function($scope, $mdSidenav) {
 $scope.toggleSideNav = function() {
  $mdSidenav('leftNav').toggle();
 };
}]);
```

```css
.ma-sidenav {
 background: rgb(16,108,200);
}

.btn-row {
 padding-top: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

.btn-toggle {
 display: inline-block;
}

.sidenav-item {
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="materialApp">
 <section ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2 ma-sidenav" md-component-id="leftNav">
   <div class="sidenav-item">Item 1</div>
   <div class="sidenav-item">Item 2</div>
   <div class="sidenav-item">Item 3</div>
   <div class="sidenav-item">Item 4</div>
  </md-sidenav>

  <md-content flex layout-padding>
   <div class="btn-row">
    <md-button class="md-raised btn-toggle" ng-click="toggleSideNav()">Toggle SideNav</md-button>
   </div>
  </md-content>
 </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thx for code. I would like to start open and the contents do not fall behind but the side? When open the content side, when closed the contents in full.

Comment: Can you share your code on jsfiddle or plunkr, so that I can fix it for you?

Comment: I own the online project , will you?

Comment: You'll have to write a little bit of custom css for achieving what you want. If you can create a jsFiddle or plunkr with your code, I can help you out.

Comment: i create a codepen, but the css  no works, take a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGmRzJ

Answer (score 0):

alas, #Gabriel's solution is not complete. from description https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api#MatSidenav

`Whether the drawer can be closed with the escape key or by clicking on the backdrop.`

but we have 3 options how to close `sidenav` and the 3d when you click on some element(?) in it. to prevent that you need to override callback or for instance I used to `sidenav` for responsive design and this answer was helpful for me https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1130#issuecomment-299888690